# GADT with Type level Bool - making (&&) type operator imply constraints for its arguments

Tags: haskell, ghc, typechecking

**In summary I am trying to understand how I can tell ghc that `a && b ~ True` should imply that `a ~ True` and `b ~ True` within the context of a GADT.**

Given a data constructor:

```
data Foo :: Bool -> * where
    ...
    Bar :: Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k)
    ...
```

and, as an example, an instance for `Eq (Foo True)`:

```
instance Eq (Foo True) where
   (Bar foo11 foo12) == (Bar foo21 foo22) = foo11 == ff21 && foo12 == foo22
   ....
```

the compiler gives the following error:

```
Could not deduce: k1 ~ k
      from the context: 'True ~ (j && k)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Bar :: forall (j :: Bool) (k :: Bool).
                          Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k),
                 in an equation for `=='
        at Main.hs:12:4-14
      or from: 'True ~ (j1 && k1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Bar :: forall (j :: Bool) (k :: Bool).
                          Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k),
                 in an equation for `=='
        at Main.hs:12:21-31
      `k1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Bar :: forall (j :: Bool) (k :: Bool).
                 Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k),
        in an equation for `=='
        at Main.hs:12:21-31
      `k' is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Bar :: forall (j :: Bool) (k :: Bool).
                 Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k),
        in an equation for `=='
        at Main.hs:12:4-14
      Expected type: Foo k
        Actual type: Foo k1
    * In the second argument of `(==)', namely `f22'
      In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `f12 == f22'
      In the expression: f11 == f21 && f12 == f22
    * Relevant bindings include
        f22 :: Foo k1 (bound at Main.hs:12:29)
        f12 :: Foo k (bound at Main.hs:12:12)
```

(and an equivalent error for j and j1)

This is obviously complaining that it doesn't know that `f12 :: Foo k` and `f22 :: Foo k1` have the same type.

Recently I have been using typelit-nat-normalise to solve what felt like a similar issue (with typenat addition), and I have searched for a similar library that may resolve these issues for bools - but to no avail.

I have found [typelevel-rewrite-rules](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelevel-rewrite-rules-1.0), which I think might enable me to write some kind of rewrite rule for this but I can't work out the syntax for telling the compiler that:

`(a && b ~ True)` implies `(a ~ True) AND (b ~ True)`. Which I believe would solve this issue.

Comment: I tried adding a `QuantifiedConstraints` to the `Bar` constructor: `((j && k) ~ True => '(j, k) ~ '(True, True))`, the `Foo` type compiled but the instance did not

Comment: The paper [Everybody's Got To Be Somewhere](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.04085.pdf) introduces the notion of defining the graph of a function inductively. You could define a GADT that reflects the structure of `(&&)`: `data And arg1 arg2 res where And1 :: And False a False; And2 :: And True a a; ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that such kind of "inversion" of a type family is impossible in current GHC, at least without unsafe functions.

Even with unsafe functions, I don't know if it is safe to add it. Kinds are weird beasts, and often contain more terms than one would expect. E.g. `type family X :: Bool` compiles, still we can not prove `X ~ 'True` nor `X ~ 'False`.

The code below does not fully answer the question, but I wanted to remark that, if we can add a few constraints to `Foo` so to carry a few singletons around, then we can write the wanted `Eq` instance.

The code below can probably be simplified further. Still, here it is. Below, I defined "conversion" functions `fooT1, fooT2` to convince GHC that in `Foo k` and `Foo j` we do have `k ~ j ~ 'True`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications,
    DataKinds, TypeOperators, KindSignatures,
    FlexibleInstances, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.Bool

data Foo :: Bool -> * where
    Bar :: (SingI j, SingI k) =>
           Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k)

fooT1 :: forall a b. (SingI a, SingI b, (a && b) ~ 'True) 
      => Foo a -> Foo b -> Foo 'True
fooT1 f _ = case (sing @a, sing @b) of
   (STrue, STrue) -> f

fooT2 :: forall a b. (SingI a, SingI b, (a && b) ~ 'True)
      => Foo a -> Foo b -> Foo 'True
fooT2 _ f = case (sing @a, sing @b) of
   (STrue, STrue) -> f

instance Eq (Foo 'True) where
   (Bar foo11 foo12) == (Bar foo21 foo22) = 
      fooT1 foo11 foo12 == fooT1 foo21 foo22 &&
      fooT2 foo11 foo12 == fooT2 foo21 foo22
```

Note that the pattern match `(STrue, STrue)` is exhaustive, and no warnings are raised by GHC.

Comment: Wow, thank you this does make the code compile :) Have never come across singletons before and just checked out the library and it seems very cool - but quite difficult to wrap your head around at first. I've been reading this very well written blog series (https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-1.html) and I think starting to get the hang of it.

Comment: Am I correct in the understanding in this instance that the `SingI` constraints represent storing a runtime witness to the Bool kinds in the data type? I'm guessing that then you can confirm that they are ~ 'True at runtime?

Comment: @SamToth That's correct. Essentially, we have two constructors `STrue :: Sing 'True` and `SFalse :: Sing 'False`, and having a value of type  `Sing b` at runtime enables us to test whether the type-level boolean `b` is true or false. I could have used `Bar :: Sing j -> Sing k -> Foo j -> Foo k -> Foo (j && k)` but that adds two extra arguments to the constructors, that we have to pass (and pattern match) each time. Using a `(SingI j, SingI k) =>...` constraint instead makes these two implicit, which is a bit more convenient.

Comment: @SamToth You also have to understand that, by default, at runtime all type-level information is gone: GHC erases types during compilation. This is usually a good thing, since after type checking types are (usually) no longer needed and erasing them leads to more efficiency. When you do need type-level information at runtime, however, you need to use something like singletons -- we now do pay a slight performance cost since we keep more info at runtime.